# Return an array during rendering template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I want to display a list of active users. I'm using FOSUserBundle on my project. I create a field on my user table that will contains the last user activity date and time and I created a listener:

```
class ActivityListener
{
    protected $tokenStorage;
    protected $userManager;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
    * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
    * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
    */
    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if ($this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

            if ( ($user instanceof UserInterface) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{

    /*
     * @Template()
     */
    public function whoIsOnlineAction()
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App:User')->getActive();
        return array('users' => $users);
    }
}
```

On my template, I added this line:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\UserController:whoIsOnlineAction')) }}
```

But when I try to log into a simple user, I got this error:
**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller must return a "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned an array ([users => ...]).").**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a twig template of the snippet that you want to render in your main template. For exemple let's call it _users.html.twig: and put into it:

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.username}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Then you render it in your method controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /*
     * @Template()
     */
    public function whoIsOnlineAction()
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App:User')->getActive();
        return $this-render('_users.html.twig', array('users' => $users));
    }
}
```

Later when you want to render it from the template:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\UserController:whoIsOnlineAction')) }}
```

It will render that snippet.

Comment: Yeah but don't recognize users. With `return $this->render('bundles/StaffBundle/header-content.html.twig', array('users' => $users));` I got this error **Variable "users" does not exist.**

Comment: I dont anderstand the template that you want to render. If it's a 3rd party bundle you need to read it's docs to learn how to override it's controller's methods.

Comment: I have my layout.html.twig in templates/bundle/FOSUserBundle folder and on this layout I added `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\UserController:whoIsOnlineAction')) }}
<ul>
    {% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.username}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}` but now I can't see nothing, and my server shutdown ** Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\www\staff-test\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query.php on line 406**

Comment: If for exemple in the action whoIsOnlineAction() renders a _users.html.twig the $users variable is only available in that template. means that this code {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\UserController:whoIsOnlineAction')) }} won't make {{ users }} available in layout.html.twig. You better follow the instruction that i gave.